# How do I delete a file from my Xoom?

Tags: motorola-xoom, delete, file-management

I downloaded a [drawing app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.drawfree&feature=search_result) for my Xoom and it saves the pictures to the local device (called "SD Card" even though it is internal space).

How do I delete those files?  I can find them to attach to email, but they don't appear in my list of "downloads".

Do I need to get another app?  Is there nothing that comes with the Xoom that lets me manage those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a file manager, and just browse to the same path that you do when you attach to email.

If the Xoom doesn't have a file manager, I recommend [Root Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer).  If you don't have root you can try another, like [Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result).

Answer (score 1):

Matthew recommended some good apps (+1) and I wanted to also recommend [ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result).  If any of the ones already mentioned don't work here is a [search of the file explorer apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=file+explorer&c=apps) in the Android Market.  Once you find one you can install it straight from the market page.